# Некорректное сравнение cmp

Tags: ассемблер

Пытаюсь написать небольшую программу для сравнения двух чисел (на NASM под Linux)

```
 section .data                            
 value1 db 6
 value2 db 77

 messege_success db "success1!"
 lenSuccessMsg equ $-messege_success

section .text          
global _start

_start: 

 mov eax,[value1]
 mov ebx,[value2]

 ;Сравнение, если eax<ebx, то переходим на success_story
 cmp eax,ebx
 jl success_story

 jmp exit_story 

 success_story:
 mov eax, 4
 mov ebx, 1
 mov ecx, messege_success
 mov edx, lenSuccessMsg
 int 80h
 jmp exit_story 


 exit_story:
 mov eax, 1
 mov ebx, 0
 int 80h
```

По идее,если eax меньше ebx то должен быть переход на метку success_story, но переход осуществяеться туда постоянно(внезависимости от значения value2, ставим мы 0 или 99 , все равно получаем переход). В чем может быть моя ошибка?

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но как дополнить его нулями?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас переменные объявлены как `db` - т.е. размером один байт. Вы перед сравнением загружаете их в 4х байтные регистры. Не знаю почему ваш ассемблер не выдал вам предупреждения, но в регистр EAX попадает значение "'u', 's', 77, 6", в EBX соответственно со сдвигом на 1 байт.

Для сравнения однобайтных значений следует использовать однобайтные регистры:

```
mov  al, [value1]
cmp  al, [value2]
```

Если по каким то причинам вам надо работать с этими байтами как с четырехбайтными значениями, надо использовать загрузку в регистр с расширением нулем:

```
movzx  eax, byte ptr [value1]
```